# xen issues in wubi ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wubi, xen

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Windows 7 from Wubi.  Now I want to install Xen on it.

I have searched a lot and read many blog.

I tried to install but when I run a command `xm list` to check whether Xen is install or not it gives me error that it **cant find hypervisor**.

Update grub command now not working as I have changed many things so should I reinstall from Wubi?

Is installing Xen on  Wubi a problem?  Should I install Ubuntu from live CD or without Wubi?

Will my windows crashed if install Ubuntu without Wubi?

My main objective is to install Xen on Ubuntu.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

XEN works with Wubi. When you install ubuntu-xen-server all you need do is change the `/boot/xen` parameters to `/wubi/boot/xen` in the primary operating system (so in this case Windows 7 and not the Wubi install). That should be the only thing you need to do.

But most manuals regarding XEN expect you have a dual boot kind of setup and not Wubi so if you do re-install I would go for a normal Ubuntu install.

Comment: How to change the /boot/xen parameters to /wubi/boot/xen in the primary operating system